# How to put a image at the very top of a doc file with python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

Here's my code :

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import excel2img

excel2img.export_img("test.xlsx","image2.png",  "Sheet1", "G13:J22")
    
document = Document('filename.docx')

paragraphs = document.paragraphs
    
paragraph = paragraphs[0]

run = paragraph.add_run()
run.add_picture('image2.png', width=Inches(6.65), height=Inches(2.02))

document.save('new.docx')
```

And here's my word output look like :

[image: output]

I don't understand how to put the image above the bold sentences "Sentences to replace below" because I cannot specify less than 0. I guess I'm not using the right way ? If you could give me some tips it would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the needful:

```
top_paragraph = document.paragraphs[0]
image_paragraph = top_paragraph.insert_paragraph_before()
image_run = image_paragraph.add_run()
image_run.add_picture("my-picture.png")
```

An inline image lives in a run. If you don't want text to appear beside it then that run needs to be in its own paragraph. Because you want it to be the very first paragraph, you need to insert its paragraph above the existing one.